# Generate a number using a button depending on a data validation list and increment it everytime it is pressed

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops, if-statement

I have 2 data validation list in which they are dependent in each other in generating a number First list is the User ID" in cell range "D3" and the list of users are in cells "B8:B15" ex. "User 1","User 2". . "User 7" and a blank. Second list is the "Account Number" in cell range "D4" and the list of account numbers are in cells "C8:C14" the list consist of "5010","5011","6010","6011","7010", "7011" and a blank. Both cells must have value first before it can generate a number by pressing a button. 
Each user has a unique list under them depending on the combination of "User ID" and "Account Number"

ex. User 1 & 5010 can generate only from 1-10 numbers, User 2 & 5010 from 11-20, User 3 & 5010 from 21-30. . User 7 & 5010 from 61-70 
and User 1 & 5011 from 101-110, User 2 & 5011 from 111-120. . User 7 & 5011 from 161-170 etc. The generated ID will also increment +1 if clicked and will reset if it is clicked 10 times.
This is my code below, I want to ask if there is a shorter way in doing it. I only finished 2 sets only in account number "5010" and "5011"

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim S1, S2 As Worksheet
Dim ID As Integer

Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set S2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set ID1_5010 = S1.Range("C18")
Set ID2_5010 = S1.Range("D18")
Set ID3_5010 = S1.Range("E18")
Set ID4_5010 = S1.Range("F18")
Set ID5_5010 = S1.Range("G18")
Set ID6_5010 = S1.Range("H18")
Set ID7_5010 = S1.Range("I18")

Set ID1_5011 = S1.Range("K18")
Set ID2_5011 = S1.Range("L18")
Set ID3_5011 = S1.Range("M18")
Set ID4_5011 = S1.Range("N18")
Set ID5_5011 = S1.Range("O18")
Set ID6_5011 = S1.Range("P18")
Set ID7_5011 = S1.Range("Q18")


If S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 1" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5010" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID1_5010 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 2" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5010" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID2_5010 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 3" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5010" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID3_5010 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 4" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5010" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID4_5010 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 5" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5010" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID5_5010 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 6" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5010" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID6_5010 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 7" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5010" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID7_5010 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 1" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5011" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID1_5011 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 2" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5011" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID2_5011 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 3" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5011" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID3_5011 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 4" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5011" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID4_5011 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 5" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5011" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID5_5011 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 6" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5011" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID6_5011 + 1

ElseIf S1.Range("D3").Value = "User 7" And S1.Range("D4").Value = "5011" Then
    S1.Range("D5").Value = ID7_5011 + 1

Else
    MsgBox "User ID or IACO needs to be filled out before generating an ID!", vbCritical

End If
End Sub
```

Any help or recommendations/ suggestions is very helpful. Thank you!

[image: This is how it looks like.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is this line `Dim S1, S2 As Worksheet` declares only S2 as Worksheet, S1 is declared as Variant, the proper should be `Dim S1 As Worksheet, S2 As Worksheet`.

Second thing, you have such conditions that you will have to hard code it. You may try pattern like this, it will allow to make some copy-paste (but be careful with it):

**UPDATE**

As far as the task changed dramatically with adding a screenshot - the code that was here first is not relevant. So updated code is here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet

' these are your ranges with data
' you need to update it
Dim range5010 As range
Dim range5011 As range
' add other needed ranges, as much as you need

Dim workRange As range  ' service variable
Dim checkCell As range  ' service variable

Set dataSheet = ActiveSheet ' Put here your sheet with data like ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_name")
                            ' I'VE USED AN "ActiveSheet" JUST FOR TEST PURPOSES.
                            ' Do not use ActiveSheet/WorkBook in production code

Dim userID As String            ' variable for user Id
Static uID As String            ' static "data holder"
Dim accountNumber As String     ' variable for account No
Static accID As String          ' static "data holder"
Dim generatedID As Long         ' variable for ID

Dim dataCol As Long, dataRow As Long ' service variables

With dataSheet
    Set range5010 = range(.Cells(17, 3), .Cells(28, 9))     ' the same as Range("C17":"I28")
    Set range5011 = range(.Cells(17, 11), .Cells(28, 17))   ' the same as Range("K17":"Q28")
    ' set other needed ranges

    userID = .Cells(3, 4)           '|
    accountNumber = .Cells(4, 4)    '| getting actual data
    generatedID = .Cells(5, 4)      '|

End With

Select Case accountNumber ' selecting the range to work with
    Case 5010
        Set workRange = range5010
    Case 5011
        Set workRange = range5011
    ' add other accounts
End Select

' Looking for needed column
For Each checkCell In workRange.Rows(1).Cells
    If checkCell.Text = userID Then
        dataCol = checkCell.Column
        Exit For
    End If
Next


' Now the logic itself
If accID = accountNumber Then   ' if account number is the same I assume that some data was already generated
    If uID = userID Then        ' if the user is the same as stored - means that data was generated and I need to update it
        For Each checkCell In range(dataSheet.Cells(workRange.Cells(1, 1).row, dataCol), dataSheet.Cells(workRange.Cells(workRange.Rows.Count, 1).row, dataCol)).Cells ' this is your hometask to understand what have happened here :)
            If checkCell = generatedID Then                                                 ' checking the id - if it matches then
                If Not checkCell.row = workRange.Cells(workRange.Rows.Count, 1).row Then    ' if it is not the last row in account range
                    generatedID = checkCell.Offset(1, 0)                                    ' taking the next Id
                    Exit For
                Else                                                                        ' in case it was last row in that account
                    generatedID = dataSheet.Cells(workRange.Rows(2).row, dataCol)           ' grab the first value
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Else    ' if the user is not the same - means that user was changed and I have to assign him the first Id value
        generatedID = checkCell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Else ' if account number  is not the same - means that I have to go to other table and grab the first Id value for certain user
    generatedID = checkCell.Offset(1, 0)
End If

accID = accountNumber   '|
uID = userID            '| update stored values

dataSheet.Cells(5, 4) = generatedID ' post new Id to worksheet

End Sub
```

This was quite interesting task, I would appreciate any comments if I missed something.

There are two "data holders" as I've called it, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement) about.

Comment: I understand this, but how do you create that whenever it is clicked again it will increment the value? and then reset again for example, the generated ID is "1" then the button is pressed again it will display "2" and when it reaches "10" value if it is pressed again it will go back to "1" again.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to your original post of how does this all look like?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot, I hope it is helpful.

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that the reset condition is met when, for example, User4 with code 5010 reaches the id 40 and it should be reset back to 30 (as per screenshot)?

Comment: Yes it should reset to 30

Comment: And final question - is the data stored on the worksheet as on screenshot?

Comment: yes, the data stored on the worksheet as on the screenshot

Comment: Nope, it wasn't last question  - is it ok that User 1 and User 2 may have same Ids?  I mean it will be tenth for user 1 is the same as first for user 2 (10).

Comment: No, each ID should be unique, actually the list should be 1-10 then 11-20 then 21-30, not 0-10, 10-20, 20-30